# There's no room on the bus; let's get off again

Tags: word-usage

I came across that sentence while I was reading `PEU/unit 80/at on and in (place)`.

> There's no room on the bus; let's get off again

The thing is a room means a part of a building enclosed by walls floor and ceil. How is it even possible to be the room in the bus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this definition of [***room***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/room) sense 1:

> 1) space, esp. enough space, to contain something or in which to do something   ⇒ "room for one more, room to move around in"